# Convert decimal to binary with billions number in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>  

int main() {
    long long *a, n, i;
    while (0 != 1) {
        printf("Enter the number to convert: ");
        scanf("%lli", &n);
        a = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof (int));
        printf("%p", a);
        for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
            a[i] = n % 2;
            n = n / 2;
        }
        printf("\nBinary of Given Number is=");
        for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            printf("%lli", a[i]);
        }
        __fpurge(stdin);
        getchar();
    }
}
```

I have this code, my teacher request input number 77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777 and convert to binary. But program can't run with this number, it's too long. So anyone can help me, how to input billion number and program can run.

Comment: Input the value as a string and then break it down one digit at a time.

Comment: can you help me write code. I do not know where to start

Comment: First do it with paper and pencil then you will likely figure out how to code it.

Comment: Start: input a string and print it out.  Then add a loop to extract each char and print it out.  Then convert each char from the encoding, (probably ASCII), to a integer 0-9 and print that out.  Then store each int in an array, write another loop to print out the array.  Then think about how to do long division by 2.....  Lots of little steps, not moving on until the current step is 100% working.  That's how you solve problems.

Comment: There's numerous "big int" libraries out there that you can peek at.

Comment: @retired-ninja It won't work one digit at a time, as 10 is not a power of 2.

Comment: At which level are you taking this course? The answer may depend on it...

Comment: @pascal Note that you *can* implement a bigint data type as an array of decimal digits.  It surely wouldn't be the most efficient way (kind the opposite), but probably the easiest and something a student may use to practice those type of algorithms.

Comment: @bob OK. I understood the first comment as meaning that a solution to binary conversion, was to process one digit at a time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input is too large for an int type you can use a string and manipulate it using the same algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isZero(const char *s, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] != '0')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void div2(char *s, int len)
{
    int remainder = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        int digit = s[i] - '0' + remainder;
        remainder = 10 * (digit % 2);
        s[i] = '0' + (digit / 2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char input[256] = "77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777";
    char bits[2048] = { 0 };

    int len = strlen(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] < '0' || input[i] > '9')
        {
            printf("%c is not a numeric digit, exiting.\n", input[i]);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    int pos = 0;
    while (!isZero(input, len))
    {
        int digit = input[len - 1] - '0';
        bits[pos++] = '0' + (digit % 2);
        div2(input, len);
    }

    len = strlen(bits);
    while (len--)
    {
        putchar(bits[len]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```